# Joomla caching error messages

Tags: caching, joomla, joomla1.5

OK, so because my Joomla 1.5 site is insanely inefficient, I've had to resort to caching in an attempt to keep the thing up and running. First, I enabled module-level caching, which had a slight benefit, but not quite enough. So I then enabled page-level caching. Performance is now much better, but there are a few associated problems, the main one being caching of error messages.

I cannot quite believe that Joomla would cache pages with error messages, but that does appear to be happening. Still, I have a whole bunch of extensions installed, so I'm not quite ready to blame core Joomla just yet. But, having looked at the code, as far as I can tell, there is no provision to not cache error messages. I've determined that errors are stored in the session, then displayed on a page via JDocumentRendererMessage. But I cannot see anything in any of the caching code (plugin, cache.php, etc.) that looks remotely like "if (messages are in the message queue) don't cache the page;"

Is anyone else familiar with this problem?

Comment: I believe that Joomla does cache the current state of the application. It is completely dependant on the component's developer to code in the necessary hooks to allow caching to function correctly. Pages with dynamic, user-specific content ought not to be cached. Of course, it would help to be using an up-to-date version of the CMS software, but I am well aware that in a lot of cases this is not possible.

Comment: This is core behaviour I'm referring to. If you can, and are willing, please try the following (in a non-live enviornment, of course!): 1. turn page caching (i.e. the plugin) on 2. remove any existing cache/page/* files 3. view a page that includes a system message. The example I'm working with is an 'invalid username/password' error, generated by a popup login box 3. grep 'Invalid username' cache/page/* - or whatever the actual message is. You should spot files. That should not happen. And, agreed, I *really* need to upgrade Joomla - with 50+ extensions, though, easier said than done ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a bug in Joomla which I [submitted a patch for](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/commit/ff75fa8544ff33a66a1ae144455e1ad7087aa413).